# Building Expo app for IOS with windows

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I was wondering if there was any way for me to build my [Expo](https://expo.io) app with Windows. Whenever I run exp build:ios, I get the following warning:

> Does not seem like WSL enabled on this machine. Download from the Windows app
> store a distribution of Linux, then in an admin powershell, please run:
>
> Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem->Linux
>
> and run the new Linux installation at least once

What app should I use for this? And even if I do it, will Expo allow me to build for IOS?

Alternatively, can I use a service like Microsoft Appcenter to build it for me?

Answer (score 8):

1. Open PowerShell as Administrator and run:

`Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux`

2. Restart your computer when prompted.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10

Answer (score 5):

Expo builds all the binaries on their servers, therefore you can do this on any OS (including Windows).  Some of the Expo tools require the Linux subsystem on Windows, therefore you need to install that, but then everything works correctly.

Answer (score 4):

1. Download Ubuntu from Windows Store
2. Open powershell as administrator and paste ***Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux***
3. Restart the computer, then run the command ***expo build:ios***

Comment: Typical Microsoft though: "Download Ubuntu? Sure! Install subsystem? You got it mate! *after installing and restart* Ooooooh. Mate. I just noticed you have Windows HOME EDITION so I'm not gonna let you do this anyway"